# how to config "--enable-preview" when using javafx:jlink in javafx-maven-plugin

Tags: javafx, openjfx, jlink

I use this plugin in my javafx project: https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin ,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.4</version>
    <configuration>
        ...
       <launcher>launcher</launcher>
       <mainClass>xxx/com.xxx.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I use **java 14 preview features** in my code, and use `javafx:jlink` command to generate **Runtime image**, but when I run **Runtime image**, error:
`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for com/xxx/Main (class file version 58.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'`.

how to config `--enable-preview` when using javafx:jlink in javafx-maven-plugin

Comment: Not sure its possible to specify VM options (or application arguments) when using `jlink`. However, you can modify the launch scripts to include `--enable-preview`. Might even be able to automate that with Maven. If you use `jpackage` then you can specify VM options with `--java-options`—see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html

Answer (score 1):

Change your javafx-maven-plugin's configuration

```
<configuration>
        ...
       <launcher>launcher</launcher>
       <mainClass>xxx/com.xxx.Main</mainClass>
       <options>
           <option>--enable-preview</option>
        </options>
</configuration>
```

*Note : Options are also added to jlink image script*